# Make PDF from TCE records on TYPO3 Backend

Tags: pdf, typo3

I have a site with some tables in the Web->List view and I have been required to add a button at the end of the form that permits BE users to create a PDF file with the data on the form using a template.

I know how to create the button and also how to create the PDF file but I can't figure out how to link form's data to the class for producing the PDF.

I don't know other ways to do this or even if there are extensions (I didn't find anything). This is my approach:

I have a button on the form:
[image]

When the user clicks the button a new window is opened and the document is created on the fly. The code used on the button is this:

```
jQuery("#create_pdf").click(function(){
  window.open("../typo3conf/ext/my_ext/lib/class.tx_myext_createPDF.php?uid='.$PA['row']['uid'].'");
});
```

This works well with the template but I don't have access to the database framework from class.tx_myext_createPDF.php (e.g $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']) and I can't retrieve data.

What I want to do is from the file class.tx_myext_createPDF.php use the uid to get the data of the record from the database to use it on the template.

I know this approach is a kind of ugly but I can't figure out a better and more simple way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up with this code:

```
jQuery("#create_pdf").click(function(){
    var pdf = jQuery("#select_pdf").val();
    if (pdf==null){
        alert("Please select an option.");
    } else {
        jQuery.getJSON(
            "../index.php",
            {
                eID:"myext",
                action:"createPDF",
                record:'.$PA['row']['uid'].',
                pdf: pdf
            },
            function(data) {
                if(data){
                    jQuery("#pdf_link").html(data);
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid Request.");
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

As I needed the TYPO3 framework to get data from the database I decided to use the eID Ajax functionality.

Instead of creating and getting the file on the fly I had to create the file in the server and return the link to it.

This works well and is not that ugly as my previous approach.

PS: `jQuery("#select_pdf").val();` refers to an additional selector that I added to specify the template to be used.